# How to make a drawing canvas with Mouse Drag in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

Any Suggestions or guidance will Help. How to create a drawing canvas in a windows phone Application.

Like the pencil tool in Paint. is it possible. A logical Expression will also Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See i Cant code the entire thing But here's a link that might help Go through it carefully.

[Drawing on canvas windows phone](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-2-drawing-shapes-with-finger)

Let me know if any confusion